# Action return JSON from CSV string object in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core

When I upgraded my .NET Core solution to 3.1 from 2.1, the action return type with string return string, but in 2.1 version return in JSON format.

How can we achieve in 3.1 version also?

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<string>> History()
    {
        var zoneId = User.GetAuthorizedZone();

        string result = await Repository.GetEventsExport();

        return result;
    }
```

DotnetCore3.1 API Output:
"Class,Series,Difficulty,Time Played,Class Duration,Event Type,First Name,Last Name,Email,\r\nZone 2,""",Piloxing,Standard,2/12/2018,2/12/2018,11:10 AM,12:05 PM,53m25s,3205000,"Ended",On Demand,53m25s,3205038,Virtual,Main Display,On Premise,0,"Strength,Mind and Body,",,,,,\r\n kail,2,"Rip Vol 26","",Power Music Rip,Standard,2/12/2018,2/12/2018,12:08 PM,1:03 PM,53m7s,3187000,"Ended",On Demand,53m7s,3187387,Virtual,Main Display,On Premise,0,"Strength",,,,,\r\nZone 2,"Rip Vol 26","",Power Music Rip,Standard,2/12/2018,2/12/2018,1:57 PM,2:02 PM,4m2s,242000,"Interrupted",On Demand,53m7s,3187387,Virtual,Main Display,On Premise,0,"Strength",,,,,\r\n

DotNetCore 2.1 Ouput:

```
[
  {
    "class": "Stream",
    "series": null,
    "difficulty": "Standard",
    "timePlayed": "22m30s",
    "timePlayedInMS": 1350575,
    "stopReason": "Ended",
    "playType": "On",
    "classDuration": "30m0s",
    "classDurationInMS": "1800000",
    "eventType": "Live",
    "screenType": "Browser",
    "accessType": "Live Stream",
    "attendance": 2,
    "firstName": "SS",
    "lastName": "PP ",
    "customId": null
  },
  {
    "zone": "Dev ",
    "class": "Stream",
    "series": null,
    "difficulty": "Standard",
    "timePlayed": "14m15s",
    "timePlayedInMS": 855380,
    "stopReason": "Ended",
    "playType": "On Demand Live Stream",
    "classDuration": "30m0s",
    "classDurationInMS": "1800000",
    "eventType": "Live",
    "screenType": "Browser",
    "attendance": 2,
    "firstName": "xxx",
    "lastName": "yyy",
    "customId": null
  }]
```

Comment: It will be difficult to get advice and answers without presenting the source code of the relevant part. Please refer to these help articles. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: CSV is a way of formatting text files, not a type of object. The code you posted here returns a simple string. Whether that string contains commas, tabs or quotes doesn't matter. What did you expect instead of that?

Comment: BTW, returning a string that needs to be parsed from a "repository" isn't very useful. The Repository pattern is meant to *hide* the storage mechanism and format so the calling code doesn't have to deal with it. It's meant to return the entities or data objects the application needs to do its job

Comment: If `result` is just values separated by commas, you can use `var values=result.Split(',');` to get an array of strings. The client would get a JSON array and still have to guess what each value meant. If the source is a full CSV text, with headers and multiple lines, a library like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) or [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) could be used to parse it into objects. There other, probably faster libraries too. Of course, that's the job of the Repository.